# Jenkinsfile with Multibranchpipline and Gitlab - how to get CHANGE_TARGET/destination of a Merge Request

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

As the env variables are only working for Multibranch-build and I'm using the Jenkinsfile. I need to get the `CHANGE_TARGET` attribute so that I could pre-merge the requests and then do a build. I've already checked the full list of env-variables, but nothing useful is there.

How do I get the following attributes with Multibranchpipline, Gitlab and Jenkinsfile?

```
CHANGE_ID
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the change ID, such as a pull request number, if supported; else unset.
CHANGE_URL
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the change URL, if supported; else unset.
CHANGE_TITLE
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the title of the change, if supported; else unset.
CHANGE_AUTHOR
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the username of the author of the proposed change, if supported; else unset.
CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the human name of the author, if supported; else unset.
CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the email address of the author, if supported; else unset.
CHANGE_TARGET
For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the target or base branch to which the change could be merged, if supported; else unset.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gitlab variables for merge request build **gitlabSourceBranch** and **gitlabTargetBranch**, for doing prebuild merge you can use the below checkout code:-

```
checkout(
    [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}']],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [
    [$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [fastForwardMode: 'FF', mergeRemote: 'origin', mergeTarget: '${gitlabTargetBranch}']],
    [$class: 'UserIdentity', email: 'abc@mail.com', name: 'user'],
    [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: "C:\Test\Merge" ]], submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [ [credentialsId: 'user', name: 'origin', url: "${gitlabTargetRepoHttpUrl}"] ]
    ])
```

For more information please follow [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work for the Multibranch Pipeline - just checked the ${env.gitlabSourceBranch} and also the ${gitlabSourceBranch}

Comment: yes, you can create single pipeline job and after getting the code with merge changes you can create a branch from that and push it to remote repository, and then you can run different stages using multibranch.